# Convert nested for loop to stream in java 11

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Convert to `Streams`:

```
private static List<Location> extractLocation(List<Location> locations){
        List<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Location l : locations){
            if(l!=null){
                final Location location = Location.builder()
                        .id(l.getId())
                        .build();
                for(Address address: l.getAddresses()){
                    if(address.getType().equals("primary")){
                        location.setPrimaryAddress(address);
                    }
                    else{
                        location.setBillingAddress(address);
                    }
                }
                locationList.add(location);
            }
        }
        return locationList;
    }
```

I am stuck after building the object. For the nested loop, since it is next step after the `Location object` is built, which `Stream method` to apply here to set primary and billing address.

```
private static List<Location> extractLocationStream(List<Location> locations){
        return locations.stream()
                .filter(location -> location!=null)
                .map(location ->
                {
                    Location l = Location.builder()
                        .id(location.getId())
                        .build();
                    location.getAddresses().stream()
                            .filter(address -> address.getType().equals("primary")).// what to do now
                })

                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

`Location` and `Address` classes:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Address{
    private int id;
    private String type;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
class Location{
    private int id;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private Address primaryAddress;
    private Address billingAddress;

}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your `Location` class have `getPrimaryAddress()`?

Comment: Or in other words, why do you have to convert a `Location` to a `Location` at all?

Comment: Please, provide the `Location` class

Comment: @Kayaman - This is legacy code. The input `Location" doesn't set primary and billing addresses but just contains list of Addresses. I realize I should have posted code for these classes as well - otherwise confusion is obvious.

Comment: @DiegoBorba - Added `Location` and `Address` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    private static List<Location> extractLocationStream(List<Location> locations) {
        return locations.stream().filter(location -> location != null).map(location -> {
            Location l = Location.builder().id(location.getId()).build();
            location.getAddresses()/*.stream()*/.forEach(address -> { // Here, stream is optional
                if ("primary".equals(address.getType())) {
                    l.setPrimaryAddress(address); //Overwrites if multiple primary
                } else {
                    l.setBillingAddress(address); //Overwrites if multiple non-primary
                }
            });
            return l;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```